# How do I load a JavaScript file with Jint in C#?

Tags: c#, javascript, jint

I want to load a JavaScript file using Jint, but I can't seem to figure it out. The documentation said I could do something like `engine.run(file1)`, but it doesn't appear to be loading any files. Do I need to do something special with the file name?

Here's my JavaScript file:

```
// test.js
status = "test";
```

Here's my C#

```
JintEngine js = new JintEngine();
js.Run("test.js");
object result = js.Run("return status;");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

If I put in code manually in `Run` it works.

```
object result = js.Run("return 2 * 21;"); // prints 42
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a workaround by manually loading the file into text myself, instead of loading it by name as mentioned here: http://jint.codeplex.com/discussions/265939

```
        StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("test.js");
        string script = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
        streamReader.Close();

        JintEngine js = new JintEngine();

        js.Run(script);
        object result = js.Run("return status;");
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I use:

```
js.Run(new StreamReader("test.js"));
```

Compact and just works.

Answer (score 1):

Even more succinctly (using your code)

```
JintEngine js = new JintEngine();
string jstr = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(test.js);
js.Run(jstr);
object result = js.Run("return status;");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 using(FileStream fs = new FileStream("test.js", FileMode.Open))
 {
    JintEngine js = JintEngine.Load(fs);
    object result = js.Run("return status;");
    Console.WriteLine(result);
 }
```

Comment: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException was unhandled
  Message=The input stream is not a valid binary format. The starting contents (in bytes) are: 73-74-61-74-75-73-20-3D-20-22-74-65-73-74-22-3B-0D ...
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.SerializationHeaderRecord.Read(__BinaryParser input)
       at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadSerializationHeaderRecord()

Comment: @Daniel, I'm not sure but the point is `Run()` expects a script to execute and not a file name;  Try reading the contents of the file manually into a string  (`File.ReadAllText()`) and then try calling `Run()` with the string.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax has changed.  When using Jint 3.0.0-beta use the Execute method instead of Run.

```
StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader("test.js");
string script = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
streamReader.Close();

Engine js = new Engine();

js.Execute(script);
object result = js.Execute("return status;");
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadKey();
```