# Return edited XML string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-parsing, jint

I'm using the the **XML for < script >** library W3C DOM Parser available [here](http://xmljs.sourceforge.net/website/documentation-w3cdom.html). (This because I'm using js inside a .NET CLI Jint program instead of a browser.)

My problem is, I edit a XML using DOMImplementation.loadXML() function and then I edit one node value, then I want to retrieve as string all the XML including the modified one:

```
 //instantiate the W3C DOM Parser
 var parser = new DOMImplementation();

 //load the XML into the parser and get the DOMDocument
 var domDoc = parser.loadXML($xmlData);

 //get the root node (in this case, it is ROOTNODE)
 var docRoot = domDoc.getDocumentElement();

 // change "name" element value
 docRoot.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).nodeValue="John";

 // try to retreive all the XML including the changed one
 $xmlData=docRoot.getXML();
```

Sample XML:

```
<name>Carlos</name>
```

All works good except the last line:

```
docRoot.getXML();
```

Which only returns the original XML as string and not the modified one.

Any idea how can I retreive all the XML as string including the modified?

Comment: Hey RandomGuy,  sorry for being Slightly off topic: I wanted to ask how you managed to import DOMImplementation in Jint. I tried but it always for a reason or another, for instance, the "alerts" are not known. did you alter the sources on any way to get it to work ? Thank you very much :)

Comment: You mean how do I imported the XML for < script > library in Jint? Well I used this method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059140/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-with-jint-in-c/16617805#16617805. Load tinyxmlsax.js and tinyxmlw3cdom.js that way.

Comment: That's basically the approach I took, unfortunately, I keep on getting an exception when executing the script.

Additional information: DOMImplementation is not defined 

Also, tinyxmlsax.js doesn't contain any declaration of DOMImplementation

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have the source code that I used at that time. I rewrote my application in C++ and used http://jsxml.sourceforge.net/ js library instead since it's much faster than C# with XML for < script >. Maybe you can also try jsxml and see if it works for you.

Comment: Alright,  I'll give it a try,  thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it replacing:

```
docRoot.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).nodeValue="John";
```

by:

```
docRoot.getElementsByTagName("name").item(0).firstChild.setNodeValue("John");
```

Seems I needed to call `firstChild` to text in the Element "name" be really replaced. With this `docRoot.getXML()` returned all the XML code including the modified one.