# JINT - Can External Javascript be Included in parsing?

Tags: jint

I am wanting to implement `JINT` in my website, with `Ace` text editor for the management to write some scripting situations in javascript. So far this looks to be fine, but I am having a hard time finding some specific information.

Essentially, I need to create some certain javascript "objects" with some functions attached to them. In normal javascript this is no problem, but I am curious if JINT can handle this scenario and allow me to load these objects from a `*.js` file when it is getting ready to run the scripts? I have dug around on this topic and not found a lot of answers; Primarily the only semi-conclusion I discovered was here; [Stackoverflow Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7059140/how-do-i-load-a-javascript-file-with-jint-in-c)

Any help is appreciated, as I am new to this entire concept of JINT and find it an interesting approach.. but with a lot of confusion. If there are other engines similar to JINT but better suited to this, recommendation would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you have instantiated the `Engine` object, you can call `Execute()` as many times as you want. So what you will do is before executing the script from your text editor, just execute the scripts that you want to include.

This should be something like this:

```
var script1 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText('script1.js');
var script2 = System.IO.File.ReadAllText('script2.js');

var engine = new Jint.Engine();
engine.Execute(script1);
engine.Execute(script2);
engine.Execute(aceditor.Text);
```

Comment: By the way, you need to use the version on Github (https://github.com/sebastienros/jint) or on NuGet (https://www.nuget.org/packages/Jint)

Comment: Thanks a lot, again, for this help. I am liking Jint, so far.

Comment: @SébastienRos-MSFT Hi..i tried copy pasting this script https://raw.githubusercontent.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/master/src/ua-parser.js inside engine.execute but i am getting An unhandled exception of type 'Jint.Runtime.JavaScriptException' occurred in Jint.dll.. Can you help..

Answer (score 0):

You can also try Edge.js, where you can import node modules